# Internet Connection Speed

Tags: connection, performance

I've been experiencing some issues with my connection speed. My router is able to get 650 kbps  download and 650 kbps upload. But when I ran a test (four times) all I got was 14 kbps. I do know the difference between bits and Bytes. my 650 kbps goes to 81.25 kBps and 14 kbps goes to 1.75 kBps and I don't want that. I've done almost all the basic diagnosis like disc cleanup, disc defragmenting, full scan, cookie deletion and none of them seem to be working to increase my speed. I use a disc program called McAfee Security Center for my laptop. And my internet service provider is Sasktel. I tried to download the iTunes program and it's taking me over an hour with 14 kbps. Is there any one who can give me any advice on increasing my connection speed. kthxbye

Answer (score 1):

Rather than first suspecting the computer, I'd check out the network infrastructure. Are you using appropriate cabling for the modem? Are the phones filtered? Are the cables close to other electronics or cabling? -- it could be EMI problems.

I'd get in contact with your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

Check and see if you have any programs that are hogging up your upload bandwidth as that may cause your download to be slow. Also check and see that your programs aren't stuck in download mode for an update that doesn't exist (this happened to me once with McAfee).

Other than that, definitely check with your ISP and get them to take a look at what's going in and out of the modem. It is possible that someone else could be stealing your bandwidth. Also try restarting the router by turning it off for 30 seconds and then turning it back on again. Some routers need to be restarted periodically for some reason. How that got past QA, I have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have cable or ADSL? If you have ADSL please specify which type (ADSL1 or ADSL2) and find out how to get the noise margins and attenuation for your connection and post them here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DSL, first replace the phone line going to the modem.  Try skipping any router you may be using and go directly to your modem.  If the speeds are still spotty there, go ahead and run a phone line from your demarc to your modem and try there.  If its PPoE dont forget to set up the connection on your system.

If you are able to check the speeds at the demarc and they are bad, you should be able to notify your provider and have them service the issue.  If the speeds are fine at your demarc then the problem is your lines coming in or some hardware/software issue.

If you are getting good speeds are the demarc you need to ensure that your filters are working, unplug everything that will put noise on your line, phones, satelite dish receiver, fax machine etc.  If the speeds improved, hook everything up one by one until you find the noisy culprit.

If you can verify its not the router, the filters, the PC, or the  phone line to the modem and the speeds are fine at the demarc you should take your modem to the ISP and have them verify that it gets good speeds there.  If it does, you need to have them investigate your line for slow throughput.

If cable, disregard the demarc information.  Try skipping the router and going straight to the modem.  try connection to a cable line that is closer to the demarc to make sure its not an issue of a bad splitter or line of cable.

You ISP should also be able to log into there router that you are connected to and view your outgoing connections.  If you are infected you tend to have a lot more outbound connections then normal.  You can also try and use a program like Wireshark to sniff your packets and see what is going on network wise.  If you are behind a router and idle, you should mostly see arp requests.  If you are getting a lot of connections on odd ports etc, you are probably infected with something. Good luck.